# SCALA - How could a function be called in a struct?

Tags: scala, function, apache-spark, struct, databricks

I build a dataframe, which is going to have a String column that is actuall a structure, turned to a JSON string.

```
val df = df_helper.select(
                     lit("some data").as("id"),
                     to_json(
                          struct(
                              col("id"),
                              col("type"),
                              col("path")
                          )
                     )).as("content")
```

I also built a function, that takes the identifier **id:String** as a parameter and spits out a string list.

```
def buildHierarchy(id:String) : List[String] = {

  val check_df = hierarchy_df.select(
    $"parent_id",
    $"id"
  ).where($"id" === id)

  val pathArray = List(id)
  val parentString = check_df.select($"parent_id").first.getString(0)

  if (parentString == null) {
    return pathArray
  }
  else {
    val pathList = buildHierarchy(parentString)
    val finalList: List[String] = pathList ++ pathArray
    return finalList
  }
}
```

I want to call this function and replace the **path** column with the result of the function. Is this possible, or is there a workaround?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Because you need to query another df you will need to deal with a join and maybe with some kind of udf in order to apply the parent search function  as join condition

Comment: it is allowed to retrieve the complete lists of id and parentId into the driver and then to generate the corresponding path on the driver itself? If you know that the size of those two ( `distinct(id, parentId)` ) is not too large you could try this approach

Comment: The ids have a very flexible hierarchy - which is why the recursion is required -, and the function is called more than a million times in a run, it's simply not cool performance-wise.. So I would think that's not the best option, @AlexandrosBiratsis but thank you :)

Comment: Exactly Eva, this what I tried to avoid with the above suggestion. Calling one million times a Spark action `check_df.select($"parent_id").first.getString(0)` I can't even imagine what the results will be. SO I am suggesting just to call collect once in the driver and then call buildHierarchy as you already nicely did :)

Comment: While I was composing my answer it suddenly made sense! I go and give it a try!! ^^ Sorry for the slow understanding, @AlexandrosBiratsis

Comment: In the end I prob have to use the suggestion of @EmiCareOfCell44 too! But this could work, thank you all! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of the following blog post I built up the hierarchy:

https://www.qubole.com/blog/processing-hierarchical-data-using-spark-graphx-pregel-api/

I included all the necessary information in my final dataframe, that I need to build up the details for each elements for the structure, along with the hierarchy path for each elements. Then as a new column I created a structure for each elements with the details.

```
val content_df = hierarchy_df.select($"path")
                                    .withColumn("content", 
                                           struct( col("id"),
                                                   col("type"),
                                                   col("path")
                                            ))
```

I exploded the path to reach each identifiers in it, but preserve the position order, to join on the content for each level in the path.

```
val exploded_df = content_df.select(
                         $"*",posexplode($"path"), 
                         $"pos".as("exploded_level"),
                         $"col".as("exploded_id"))
```

Then finally, join the content with the path, and aggregate the content into a path that contains all the content for each level.

```
val level_content_df = exploded_df.as("e")
           .join(content_df.as("ouc"), col("e.col") === col("ouc.id"), "left")
                      .select($"e.*", $"ouc.content".as("content"))

val pathFull_df = level_content_df
            .groupBy(col("id").as("id"))
            .agg(sort_array(collect_list("content")).as("pathFull"))
```

And then finally I just put the whole thing together again :)

```
val content_with_path_df = content_df.as("ou")
              .join(pathFull_df.as("opf"), col("ou.id") === col("opf.id"), "left")
              .select($"ou.*", $"opf.pathFull".as("pathFull"))
```

Feel free to reach out if it doesn't make sense, it took a while for me to make it happen! :D